# How to get the incoming argument of caller function in C or ASM

Tags: c, x86

I would like to access the data from the incoming arguments of the caller function *A* in function *B*. Is there is a way to do so?

```
#define get_caller_incoming_arg(call) 0
void B(int z)
{
    int _arg0  = get_caller_incoming_arg(0);
    printf ("in A(arg0): %x\n", _arg0);
    printf ("in B: %x\n", z);
}

void A(int x)
{
    int buff[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        buff[i] = i + 5;

    B(buff[1]);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    A(0xdeadbeef);
    return 0;
}
```

Target machine is x86_64 running OSX and compiler is clang

Comment: 32-bit or 64-bit?  Linux or Windows? What compiler?

Comment: I will fix the question. It's 64-bit on OSX with clang. But isn't 64-bit ABI the same for most environments?

Comment: Yes the x86_64 ABI is pretty consistent, but you didn't say you were using 64-bit before.  :)  Next question: is the parent function always the same function, or do you need it to work for different parent functions which may have different signatures?

Comment: Signature regarding incoming arguments is the same, but the size of the local arguments in the actual function I am interested in is not _int but[10]_ but bigger. Does it matter? Let's assume a fixed size of local variables - I will make the calculations later on.

Comment: And you rejected the option of passing an extra parameter why?

Comment: What's the purpose of this ? It's rather unusual and note very clean.

Comment: :) I am writing an hook function for an executable - and trying to learn some x86_64 asm in between.

Comment: To get previos rbp (if you compile with -fno-omit-frame-pointer) and passed parameters should be at addresses rbp+8, rbp+16 in case your stack 8 bit aligned. Something like that ?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a global variable and then pass the argument value to that variable as in the code

```
#define get_caller_incoming_arg(call) 0
int value=0;
void B(int z)
{
 int _arg0  = get_caller_incoming_arg(0);
 int valueofA=value;
 printf ("in A(arg0): %x\n", _arg0);
 printf ("in B: %x\n", z);
}

void A(int x)
{
 int buff[10];
 value=x;
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    buff[i] = i + 5;

 B(buff[1]);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  A(0xdeadbeef);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is more complex than your solution. I can't change the executable so it must be done through assembly - the code in C was just an example for the problem.  See the comments on my question.